# Overflow-x is scroll and overflow-y is overlay at the same time

Tags: html, css

Imagine I have  container

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
  overflow-y: overlay;
  
  max-height: 47px;
}

.item {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
  background: #dadada;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item special">
    CONTENT #1
    <div>
      Additional Content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">CONTENT #2</div>
  <div class="item">CONTENT #3</div>
  <div class="item">CONTENT #4</div>
  <div class="item">CONTENT #5</div>
  <div class="item">CONTENT #6</div>
  <div class="item">CONTENT #7</div>
</div>
```

All that I want that the first item with an additional content is overlayed the scrollable container. I would like to get something like that:

[image]

Is it possible with pure CSS?

PS. In the future it's supposed to be shown and hidden, that's why I need such a weird thing.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this snippet can you give you some sort of hint on how to resolve your issue.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
  overflow-y: overlay;
  
  max-height: 47px;
}

.item {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
  background: #dadada;
}

.item.special{
     min-height: 100px;
     position: relative;
     overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item special">
    CONTENT #1
    <div>
      Additional Content
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="item">CONTENT #2</div>
  <div class="item">CONTENT #3</div>
  <div class="item">CONTENT #4</div>
  <div class="item">CONTENT #5</div>
  <div class="item">CONTENT #6</div>
  <div class="item">CONTENT #7</div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: This element with additional content can occur in the middle of the list. Of course, to expand and show an additional content I can remove it from container, and add before the container. But it won't looks smooth enough.